# Git alias to delete remote branch

Tags: git, alias

I am trying to make an alias to delete a remote branch but I can't seem to get it, here is my latest attempt that I really expected to work but no luck.

```
rmrb = !git push origin :$1
```

I also tried, `rmrb = branch -r -d` but this doesn't do the same thing as `git push origin :<branch>`.

Does anyone know if this is possible or have an existing alias to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You just have to define it like this:

```
[alias]
    rmrb = "push --delete origin"
```

And do `git rmrb mybranch`

Comment: Seems simpler than my option. +1 (and 15. more. votes. to. go. before. gold!)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a shell function would be easier?

```
[alias]
    rmrb = "!f() { git push origin :$1; }; f"
```

Or you can use `sh`:

```
[alias]
   rmrb = !sh -c 'git push origin :$1' -
```