# How to delete all git aliases at once?

Tags: git, terminal

How can I delete all existing git aliases at once? I tried *git config --unset-all ...* but was unable to figure out the correct syntax for this command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
git config [--global] --remove-section alias
```

Answer (score 6):

You can remove it by deleting that line from the configuration file.

This is the command for removing the alias

```
git config --global --unset alias.YourAlias
```

Also this might be useful for you 
[Git alias to delete remote branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9125156/git-alias-to-delete-remote-branch)

Answer (score 5):

Easiest to just edit your config file directly.

Comment: I configure all my aliases with a shell script and the script should remove the existing aliases in the first step. So editing the config file is not an option for me.